# How to inspect an element with multi attributes by OR operator in Page Objects model in watir?

Tags: automated-testing, xpath, page-objects, watir-webdriver

I have a problem when trying to find an element with the different attribute as sample bellow

```
<i>bold</i>
Sometime
<i class='icon'/i>
```

I want to try inspecting this element with OR operator in PageObject

For example: `i(:icon_bold, text: 'bold' OR class: 'icon')` (just example, this is not correct)

So please help me to give the correct syntax to locator.

Comment: Why not just write a conditional that tries to find it by using one identifier, else try the second identifier?

Comment: Thanks for your consider. I have to use xpath  i(:bold_icon, xpath: ".//i[text()='bold' or @class='icon']"). I just want different way and better than using xpath.

Comment: <div class="input-content btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
<div class="input-label">Style:</div>
<label class="btn btn-default btn-sm ">
<i class="icon_i“></i>
<i class="icon_b“></i>
<i class="icon_u“></i>
</div>
…

Some time

<div class="input-content btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
<div class="input-label">Style:</div>
<label class="btn btn-default btn-sm ">
<i>I</i>
<i>B</i>
<i>U</i>
</div>
…